# Counting the number $\mathbb{F}_{p^r}$ points on the elliptic curve $E_n: y^2=x^3-n^2x$ when $p$ is a prime dividing $2n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, elliptic-curves

Let $E_n$ be the elliptic curve defined by $y^2=x^3-n^2x$, and let $\mathbb{F}_{p^r}$ be a finite field of $p^r$ elements, where $p$ is prime and divides $n$. How can I determine how many points the curve has on such field? I found this problem on the book "Introduction to elliptic curves and modular forms" chapter II: I'm telling this because the book explicitly states that no tool coming from algebraic geometry will be needed so I think it is possible to find a solution to this problem without any algebraic geometry.

My attempt up to now has led me to approach the solution of the case $r=1$ (at least I hope): I considered two cases:

$\bullet$ (case 1) $p\mid 2$ and $p \nmid n$ $\Longrightarrow$ $p=2$ $\Longrightarrow$ $E_n:y^2=x^3-x$

In this case $E_n(\mathbb{F}_2)=\{(0,0),( 1,0)\}$ and so $\#E_n(\mathbb{F}_2)=2$

$\bullet$ (case 2) $p \mid n$ $\Longrightarrow$ $E_n:y^2=x^3$

$\mathbb{F}_p = \{0,1,\ldots,p-1\}$ and the points on the curve are of the type $(a^3,a^2)$ $\forall a \in \mathbb{F}_p$ and are all different since:

if $a^2=b^2$ with $a\neq b$ then because $p$ is prime $a^2a\neq b^2b$ and so $a^3 \neq b^3$. So they are exactly $p$ points.

1. Is my attempt correct or at least in the right direction?
2. Independently on the answer to the previous question, what's the solution to the whole problem, so including also the cases $r\neq 1$?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Concerning the title there were two typos I've just corrected: one of then is the fact that p divides 2n and not only n. Concerning case (2) I justified it showing that sobstituting all values in $a$, we obtain always a different point. I'm glad my counting is correct, but still the general case $r \neq 1$ is a mistery to me.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. The question makes sense now!

Comment: About $r>1$. Including the point at infinity you always have exactly $p^r+1$ points on the curve. Squaring is bijective in $\Bbb{F}_{2^r}$, so to each $x\in\Bbb{F}_{2^r}$ there is a unique $y=\sqrt{x^3-x}\in\Bbb{F}_{2^r}$. In case (2) the argument (from my now deleted comment) leading to your parametrization works. Let $a=y/x$ whenever $x\neq0$. It follows easily that $x=a^2, y=a^3$, and we can choose $a$ to be any non-zero element of $\Bbb{F}_{p^r}$. If $x=0$, then $y=0$ also. The point at infinity brings the tally up to $p^r+1$.

Comment: In other words, it is not enough to show that the points you get for different choices of $a$ are distinct. You need justify why ALL the solutions are of that form.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes you are totally right, I didn't justify the parametrization, now your correction is clear. Isn't the generalization to $r>1$ "too easy"? I mean, for a generic $r$, $n$ is not always congruent to zero anymore, and in those cases the equation reads $E_n:y^2=x^3-n^2x$ How can we justify that parametrization then?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: Whenever $p\mid n$ we have $n^2x=0$ for all $x\in\Bbb{F}_{p^r}$. That's becase $px=0$ for all $x\in\Bbb{F}_{p^r}$.

Comment: I need to check one thing (many students make a mistake here). Do you know what $\Bbb{F}_{p^r}$ is? Most importantly, do you know that it is NOT the integers modulo $p^r$. If $p\equiv3\pmod4$ we can construct $\Bbb{F}_{p^2}=\{a+bi\mid a,b\in\Bbb{F}_p\}$, $i^2=-1$. If $p\equiv1\pmod4$ we need some other square root instead of $\sqrt{-1}$. With $r>2$ it is a bit more complicated.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I was considering $\mathbb{F}_{p^r}$ to be the Galois group of $p^r$ elements, and interpreting it as $\mathbb{Z}_p+\mathbb{Z}_pt+\ldots+\mathbb{Z}_pt^{r-1}$, (mod an irred. polyn. of degree r) . I tried by brute force sobstituting two different polynomials (one for $x$ and one for $y$) but didn't conclude anything. But from your comment it came up to my mind that the coefficients of any of these polynomials are in $Z_p$ and so multiplying one of such polynomials by $p$ we get a polynomial with all coefficients congruent to 0 ! Am I interpreting correctly?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen  Moreover, always by brute force I was trying to see why squaring is bijective in $\mathbb{F}_{2^r}$ (I was trying by induction on $r$) but again now I'm starting to think that it is not the correct (or smartest) way to proceed...or is it?

Comment: Squaring is a homomorphism from $\Bbb{F}_{2^r}$ to itself (both as additive groups and as fields). Because $x^2=0\implies x=0$ in **any** field, the kernel is trivial. Hence it is injective. Because the set is finite injectivity implies surjectivity (and bijectivity). Induction on $r$ is pointless, because there is no relation between $\Bbb{F}_{2^r}$ and $\Bbb{F}_{2^{r+1}}$. The field $\Bbb{F}_{2^n}$ is a subfield of $\Bbb{F}_{2^m}$ if and only if $n\mid m$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen It is all clear.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Feel free to compile an answer, if so inclined. That way you may get feedback from others as well.